# fullcalendar v4 modif ajax problem + syntax error with event.setDates

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

problem syntax setDates fullcalendar v4, Someone could explain to me how to add the all day option, because I tried this, it does not seem to work properly.

```
event.setDates(json.start, json.end, json.allDay);
```

in doc

```
event.setDates( start, end, [ options ] )
```

options is an optional plain object that can have the following property:

allDay — true or false. will modify this event’s allDay property.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setDates

thanks for your help for a question that may seem silly

I tried this (in method return ajax)

```
event.setDates(json.start, json.end, json.allDay);  -> not work
```

andthis :

```
event.setStart(json.start);
event.setEnd(json.end);
event.setAllDay(json.allDay);
```

but it modifies the event in a strange way: the end day is set to 01/01/1970

if I reload the page, the information returned is correct, so the database has the correct end date, it means that my code is correct and that it comes from the method used in fullcalendar, or it misses an option that I do not know not, in order to keep the end day intact ?

the ultimate goal, being to update the allDay option by keeping the end date

Comment: "options is a .... **plain object**" the documentation makes it very clear. Do you understand what an object is and how to declare one? `{ allDay: json.allDay}` for example would declare a simple object containing one property named "allDay". Right now that object only has that one property which is recognised by fullCalendar but I'd guess they designed it like that so they can add more options in future without changing the function signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a quite common pattern that options is an object.

Assuming your value is just a boolean, it should be like this:

```
event.setDates(json.start, json.end, { allDay: json.allDay} );
```